# Grabbing Google Directions gadget from Ajax call

Tags: html, ajax, google-maps

I am trying to throw together a website using Ajax for the first time, to finally get with the times and figure it out. So far it is nothing but HTML pages and a bit of JS. Using some basic AJAX script I found online, I have the main index.htm which has a title, navigation, and content divs. The Ajax calls grab other content includes (which are just files with text content for the most part) to throw into the content div. For the most part it works, except for when I am trying to add the Google Directions gadget. When I add the script code it gives me to a file and call that file, there is no noticeable output.

Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong or what I'm missing?

Comment: could you link to the project or provide some code please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am understanding you correctly this is an unnecessary use of AJAX. From what it seems like you want to do is load JavaScript via a JavaScript call. This can be accomplished using either method described [here](http://www.codehouse.com/javascript/articles/external/). Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function dhtmlLoadScript(url)
{
   var e = document.createElement("script");
   e.src = url;
   e.type="text/javascript";
   document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(e);
}

onload = function()
{
   dhtmlLoadScript("dhtml_way.js");
}

</script>
```

If the above link does not help or I am misunderstanding your question please provide further clarification or some sort of code example.

**Following up on your comment**

Here is a work around for your gadget, the below code would be on your main page (the one that is initially loaded). Here is my test HTML page:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  var gadget;

  function getGadgetAndMove(node)
  {
    gadget = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0];
    node.appendChild(gadget); 
    gadget.style.visibility = "visible";
    gadget.style.display = "inline-block";
  }
  </script>
  <style>
  .ig_reset, .ig_tbl_line { visibility:hidden;}
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div onclick="getGadgetAndMove(this);">Test</div>
</body>
  <script src="http://www.gmodules.com/ig/ifr?url=http://hosting.gmodules.com/ig/gadgets/file/114281111391296844949/driving-directions.xml&amp;up_fromLocation=&amp;up_myLocations=1600%20Amphitheatre%20Pkway%2C%20Mountain%20View%2C%20CA&amp;synd=open&amp;w=320&amp;h=55&amp;title=Directions+by+Google+Maps&amp;brand=light&amp;lang=en&amp;country=US&amp;border=%23ffffff%7C3px%2C1px+solid+%23999999&amp;output=js"></script>
</html>
```

If you need further explanation please let me know.

Comment: While that does help (I've never been able to figure out how to add js src links dynamically), I'm not quite sure if that helps my particular problem. I'm using the AJAX to load separate pages (for certain design reasons) but one of the pages has the google directions gadget. From what I've read AJAX can't load cross site scripts, and that's where I think the problem is coming in. Does this solution work around that?

Answer (score 0):

I believe I know what you want to accomplish, because I ran into the same problem. And I found a solution. So I would say that no it is not an improper use of ajax, because you could run into this in some circumstances.

Put the directions gadget not directly in the page content that is being loaded via ajax, but in a separate file such as "directionsgadget.html" (insert the script tag for the gadget in this file).

Then use an iframe with src="/path/to/directionsgadget.html" in your ajax loaded content.

The gadget should get loaded this way.

If you want the gadget centered within the iframe, you can wrap the script tag in directionsgadget.html in a div with a set width and style="margin:0px auto". That will center the gadget.

Here is an example:

Your main page is "index.html", and contains a div that will contain ajax loaded content:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $.ajax({
        url: 'ajaxcontent.html',
        success: function(returndata){ $('#ajaxcontent').html(returndata); }
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="ajaxcontent"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Then you have a file with the content that is to be loaded via ajax, and this has among other things a google gadget. Were not going to put the gadget directly here, but were going to put it in a separate file and point to it with an iframe. Let's call this first file ajaxcontent.html, as indicated in the ajax call in the head section of the first file:

```
  <span>Here is some content that will be loaded onto the main page via ajax.</span><br />
  <span>Among other things, there is a google directions gadget that will be loaded.</span>
  <div id="getdirections" style="margin:0px auto;">
    <iframe style="width:365px;height:216px;" src="directions.html"></iframe>
  </div>
```

Now we will put the script for the google gadget itself in a separate file "directions.html" (as indicated in the src of the iframe above), and in order for the rendered gadget to be centered we are going to wrap the script tag within a div just so:

```
<div style="width:336px;height:116px;margin:0px auto;">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.gmodules.com/ig/ifr?url=http://hosting.gmodules.com/ig/gadgets/file/114281111391296844949/driving-directions.xml&amp;up_fromLocation=&amp;up_myLocations=_a_bunch_of_information_with_personal_list_of_locations_&amp;synd=open&amp;w=320&amp;h=55&amp;title=Street+directions+by+Google+Maps&amp;brand=light&amp;lang=it&amp;country=ALL&amp;border=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.gmodules.com%2Fig%2Fimages%2F&amp;output=js"></script>
</div>
```

I hope this example was clear enough!